# location.getlongitude() and getlatitude() only updating every 100-300 seconds

Tags: java, android, location

I'm working on an application that has a feature in which GPS position is tracked to draw a map.

Essentially, every second, I am saving a point (containing latitude and longitude, as well as other info) to an array, then every 15 seconds I save the array to my database, and send all the info to the server once the trip is over.

I get the location each second using Location.getLatitude() and Location.getLongitude(). However, when looking at the file sent to the server after a trip, the longitude and latitude only change every 100 to 300 seconds (recording while in a car, so it should be changing a lot more often) - on a 9km trip, which took 24 minutes, I only have 8 different latitude/longitude combos recorded (including start and finish)

Other things I'm recording in the points are being updated each second as they should, so it's purely a longitude/latitude problem.

Is there something I need to do for location.getLongitude() to update more frequently? Or another way of getting longitude/latitude that would work better

Thanks

Comment: _"I get the location each second using Location.getLatitude() and Location.getLongitude()."_ That doesn't really tell us how you are getting the location. Have you requested location updates? Or are you relying on something like `getLastKnownLocation()`? Are you perhaps using some mysterious "GpsTracker" class going in circles around the internet and providing people antipatterns for many years already? Basically in your case you should request location updates and receive them in the `onLocationChanged()` callback.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your location request set interval and fastest interval to a smaller number. Something like this:

```
 private val UPDATE_INTERVAL = (30 * 1000).toLong()  /* 30 secs */
 private val FASTEST_INTERVAL: Long = 10000 /* 10 sec */
```

And then create your locationRequest:

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        locationRequest.interval = UPDATE_INTERVAL
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = FASTEST_INTERVAL
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
```

Comment: I currently have update_interval = 8000, fastest = 5000, priority_high_accuracy and displacement = 80, so this doesn't explain why I have such a low frequency of position updating

Answer (score 0):

i have using myLocationManager.

You can change **UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS** property what you want

and observe mLocationCalback for location events.

```
class MyLocationManager constructor( var context: Context  ) {

    private var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
    var locationStatus = BehaviorSubject.create<LOCATION_STATUS>()
    /**
     * Provides access to the Location Settings API.
     */
    var mSettingsClient: SettingsClient? = null
    /**
     * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
     */
    private var mLocationRequest: LocationRequest? = null

    /**
     * Callback for Location events.
     */
    var mLocationCallback: LocationCallback? = null

    /**
     * Stores the types of location services the client is interested in using. Used for checking
     * settings to determine if the device has optimal location settings.
     */
    private var mLocationSettingsRequest: LocationSettingsRequest? = null

    /**
     * Constant used in the location settings dialog.
     */
    private val REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1

    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    private val UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS: Long = 60000

    private val FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2

    init {
        initializeLocationManager()
    }

    private fun initializeLocationManager() {
        if (mSettingsClient == null) {
            mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context)
        }

        if (fusedLocationClient == null) {
            fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
        }

        createLocationServices()
    }

    private fun createLocationServices() {
        createLocationCallback()
        createLocationRequest()
        buildLocationSettingsRequest()
    }

    companion object {
        enum class LOCATION_STATUS {
            REQUIRE_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        }
    }

    private fun createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()

        // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
        // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
        // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
        // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
        mLocationRequest?.interval = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS

        // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
        // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
        mLocationRequest?.fastestInterval = FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS

        mLocationRequest?.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    }

    private fun buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        mLocationRequest?.let { builder.addLocationRequest(it) }
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build()
    }

    /**
     * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi. Note: we don't call this unless location
     * runtime permission has been granted.
     */
    private fun startLocationUpdates(activity: Activity, justControl: Boolean = false) {
        // Begin by checking if the device has the necessary location settings.
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            mSettingsClient?.let {
                it.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(activity) {
                        fusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(
                            mLocationRequest,
                            mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper()
                        )
                    }.addOnFailureListener(activity) { e ->
                        val statusCode = (e as ApiException).statusCode
                        when (statusCode) {
                            LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> {
                                try {
                                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                    // result in onActivityResult().
                                    if (!justControl) {
                                        val rae = e as ResolvableApiException
                                        rae.startResolutionForResult(
                                            activity,
                                            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS
                                        )
                                    }

                                } catch (sie: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                                }

                            }
                            LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                                val errorMessage =
                                    "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " + "fixed here. Fix in Settings."

                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a callback for receiving location events.
     */

    private fun createLocationCallback() {
        mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                locationResult?.lastLocation?.let {
                    // fetched location
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getLastKnowLocation(activity: Activity, justControl: Boolean = false) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            fusedLocationClient?.let {
                it.lastLocation
                    .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                        location?.let {
                            // fetched last know location
                        } ?: startLocationUpdates(activity, justControl)
                    }
            }
        } else {
            locationStatus.onNext(LOCATION_STATUS.REQUIRE_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        }
    }


    private fun stopLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationClient?.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
    }


}
```

then add permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```